# Catalog Price Rule not applying

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, catalog-price-rules

I have tried pretty much everything to get this to work. I am running `Magento 1.8.1`. I made a price rule to give a certain customer group 50% off on products. Then when I am displaying the price of a product on product view it doesn't show the updated price for the customer groups. Is this still a bug? I read in 50 million articles that it was fixed in `1.8.1`.

I dont know if this has anything to do with it. However, when I created my first catalog price rule, a rule that i never created popped up called discount I think with the same amount off. I deleted that, hence I didn't need it. Same thing happened when I created a shopping cart price rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that `Advanced Custom Options` which is what I am using in this particular website does not support catalog price rules. They have made a work around, but I see little to no use for it. Hopes this helps someone.